# Bundle Update Unicorn Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.0.1 is available and trying to update to that version (currently on version 4.0)

I'm running `bundle update` and it starts to work ok but then getting an error that seems to be about Unicorn so the whole thing is aborted. The error is as follows:

```
Installing unicorn (4.7.0)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for SIZEOF_OFF_T in ruby.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:430:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.
```

Any idea how I can get round this problem?

**GEM FILE**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.1'
gem "figaro"
gem 'unicorn'
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem 'memcachier'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'devise'
```

Comment: Did you recently update your operating system?

Comment: Hmmm! in fact I did - to Mavericks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having upgraded to Mavericks OS recently (and the new version of XCode) I needed to agree to the Xcode Terms & Conditions before the bundle update would work.

Anyway - all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
brew update
```

I'm not so familiar with unicorn, but when you upgrade to a new operating system, that can sometimes be required to get gems and plugins to work properly.

Comment: Yes, run bundle update after.  Actually, bundle install and then bundle update.

Comment: well the brew bit seemed to go well but getting the same error after bundle update

Comment: can you post your gem file?

Comment: Also, although it won't always make a difference, make  sure your server is off and not on in another terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few ideas.

1. change your gem file to the following:

   ```
   gem "unicorn", "~> 4.7.0"
   ```
2. I don't use the ruby gems website often.  I usually just look at github, but according to the website, there are some dependancies you don't have.

[image: RubyGems screenshot]

Comment: This now creates the same error using `install` which worked fine before.

Comment: and actually the 4.6.3 version has the same dependencies so I don't think it's an issue with that